# SSRS 2008 R2 - User Subscriptions Mysteriously Disappear

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a question regarding 'Subscriptions' for SQL Server Reporting Services, Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Users are granted access to setup their own 'Subscriptions' and they are able to do so successfully.

After a few days the 'Subscriptions' are mysteriously disappearing and the users are not receiving the report summary in their email. Users then have to go back into the Subscriptions page and create a new Subscription which then again seems to vanish on its own. I have looked all over the web and have not been able to find any information on this particular issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you use SSRS in native or SharePoint Integration mode? This issue could be generated by changes in report related to the subscription. Use [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/List-all-SSRS-subscriptions-968ae4d5) to see if the subscription is deleted or not taking in account by SSRS. Also don't trust users at all, reproduce the issue by yourself to obviate human misdone practices.

Comment: SSRS is being used in native mode and the users are utilizing Standard Subscriptions. I will follow up on the link you provided me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you modify alernate access mapping, Subscriptions disapear because SSRS keep in database the access zone when the subscription has been created by the user.

To fixed that, youd need to modify in SQL the column ReportZone of datatable [ReportingServiceDatabase].Subscriptions by the correct Zone for each subscription. The "ReportZone" column is based on SPUrlZone enumeration, so "Default" Zone is 0 and "Extranet" Zone is 4.